# Documents in Firestore are being deleted immediately after being added or set

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

**what i am trying to do is show a button if data exists and hide if it doesn't **

```
applyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Map<String, Object> applicantsData = new HashMap<>();

                    applicantsData.put("name", userId);
                    applicantsData.put("hobby", "swimming");
                    applicantsData.put("number", count);
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user")
                            .document(companyId).collection("post").document(postId)
                            .collection("applicants").add(applicantsData);

                    ButtonVisibility();

                });
```

**this is the applyButton it should set applybutton invisible after being clicked and make unapply visible**

```
unApplyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            documentReference.collection("post").document(postId).collection("applicants")
                    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                    for (DocumentChange doc : value.getDocumentChanges())
                    {
                        if(doc.getDocument().get("name").toString().equals(userId))
                        {
                            doc.getDocument().getReference().delete();
                        }
                    }
                    ButtonVisibility();
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

**this is the unapplyButton it should also set unapply button invisible after being clicked and apply button visible**

```
private void ButtonVisibility()
{
    documentReference.collection("post").document(postId).collection("applicants")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error)
        {
            if(!value.isEmpty())
            {
                for (DocumentChange doc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    if (doc.getDocument().get("name").toString().equals(userId)) {
                        alreadyApplied = true;
```

> when it enters here already alpplied becomes true and thats ok but after the loop is finsihed it is back to false(i made a toast and it says true here)

```
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alreadyApplied = false;
            }
```

> it becomes false here for some reason after being true in the loop(i did a toast and it says false)

```
            if(alreadyApplied)
            {
                applyButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                unApplyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                applyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                unApplyButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**this is the function that is being called after adding or deleting anything from database**

on the first for each buttons it works perfectly . but after that when click apply button it adds the data to firestore and deletes it instantly.

i would really appreciate some help here

Comment: To make sure this is not caused by your interaction with Firestore, could you please confirm whether the information you add to your database is being present in the Firestore?

Comment: yes it is presented

Comment: when i click apply first time it works( adds data to firestore & and apply button becomes invisible & unapply button becomes visible) ,same as for unapply button it works perfectly it deletes data and visibility works , but when i click apply another time it adds then deletes immediately